# Creating a gui from Quickly/Python and binding with a console app

Tags: command-line

i want to create a gui for a console application called Prozilla (available in ppas). Please provide me some links of tutorials which you think, might help me to do it. I like to know how to send commands/parameters and read the progress from the console app. Examples are always admired!Thanks a lot!